# Third character in textbox event

Tags: javascript, events, event-handling, dom-events

I have a textbox which has a maxlength of 3 characters. This is for entering in currency codes e.g. USD, GBP, EUR.

I have an `onchange` event on the textbox so that when a user enters the currency code a description is displayed next to the textbox e.g. US Dollar, Pound Sterling, Euro.

I want to know if there is a way to have the `onchange` fire or have my function called when the user has entered three characters so that the description is displayed instantly instead of when they click out of the box.

Comment: Can you show us your code?

Comment: `onchange` fires when the text changes, not when they click outside.

Comment: Take a look at this **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FXeq3/)**, I think it is what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using jQuery you could do it using keyup, e.g.:

```
$('#textbox').keyup( function() {
    if ( $('#textbox').val().length >= 3 ) {
        //do a thing
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Call this function when on whatever you want and ofcourse with your elements id

```
function display()
{
 var value = document.getElementById('yourInputBox').value;
 if(value.length<3)
 return;
 else
 {
   document.getElementById('youroutputBox').innerHTML = value;

 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. At the moment my display method is called in the onchange event of the textbox. Where should I be calling the display method from now?

Comment: @dos better use onkeyup event